# Copy pdf annotations via C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have a stream (PDF file with annotations) and another stream (the same PDF file without annotations). I use streams because I need to execute this operations in memory.
I need to copy annotations from first document to another. Annotations can be different: comments, highlighting and other. So it is better to copy annotations without parsing it.

Can you advice me some helpful PDF library for .NET? And some sample for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using ITextSharp which is forked from IText (a java implemenation fpr pdf editing).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

http://itextpdf.com/

Edit - this is what you need to do (untested but shoul be close):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

// return processed stream (a new MemoryStream) 
public Stream copyAnnotations(Stream sourcePdfStream, Stream destinationPdfStream)
{
    // Create new document (IText)
    Document outdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    // Seek to Stream start and create Reader for input PDF
    m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    PdfReader inputPdfReader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfStream);

    // Seek to Stream start and create Reader for destination PDF
    m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    PdfReader destinationPdfReader = new PdfReader(destinationPdfStream);

    // Create a PdfWriter from for new a pdf destination stream
    // You should write into a new stream here!
    Stream processedPdf = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(outdoc, processedPdf);

    // do not close stream if we've read everything
    pdfw.CloseStream = false;

    // Open document
    outdoc.Open();

    // get number of pages
    int numPagesIn = inputPdfReader.NumberOfPages;
    int numPagesOut = destinationPdfReader.NumberOfPages;

    int max = numPagesIn;

    // Process max number of pages
    if (max<numPagesOut)
    {
        throw new Exception("Impossible - different number of pages");
    }
    int i = 0;

    // Process Pdf pages
    while (i < max)
    {
        // Import pages from corresponding reader
        PdfImportedPage pageIn = writer.inputPdfReader(reader, i);
        PdfImportedPage pageOut = writer.destinationPdfReader(reader, i);

        // Get named destinations (annotations
        List<Annotations> toBeAdded = ParseInAndOutAndGetAnnotations(pageIn, pageOut);

        // add your annotations
        foreach (Annotation anno in toBeAdded) pageOut.Add(anno);

        // Add processed page to output PDFWriter
        outdoc.Add(pageOut);
    }

    // PDF creation finished
    outdoc.Close();

    // your new destination stream is processedPdf
    return processedPdf;
}
```

The implementation of ParseInAndOutAndGetAnnotations(pageIn, pageOut) needs to reflect your annotations.

Here is a good example with annotations: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/internal/PdfAnnotationsImp.java.htm

Comment: I tried to use ITextSharp, but I didn't find any good sample for copying annotations.

Comment: I've added a small sample - you need to adapt it - it's just adding an annotation. It is easy to parse through each page with iTextSharp - that's what you need to do.

Comment: I've change my example - you just need to implement your annotation comparer depending on the type of annotations - e.g. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/internal/PdfAnnotationsImp.java.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. iTextSharp is great library, but sometimes not enough examples.

Comment: can you check your code?  You're missing quite a few variable decelerations

Comment: Actual implementation of `ParseInAndOutAndGetAnnotations` is missing and the link to which it points is dead, so noway to guess the method implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example for iTextSharp to approach your problem (this example copies a list of pdf files with annotations into a new pdf file):

```
var output = new MemoryStream();

using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70f, 70f, 20f, 20f))
{
    var readers = new List<PdfReader>();
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

    writer.CloseStream = false;

    document.Open();

    const Int32 requiredWidth = 500;
    const Int32 zeroBottom = 647;
    const Int32 left = 50;

    Action<String, Action> inlcudePdfInDocument = (filename, e) =>
    {
         var reader = new PdfReader(filename);
         readers.Add(reader);

         var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
         for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
         { 
             e?.Invoke();
             var imp = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, (i + 1));

             var scale = requiredWidth / imp.Width;
             var height = imp.Height * scale;

             writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp, scale, 0, 0, scale, left, zeroBottom - height);

             var annots = reader.GetPageN(i + 1).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
             if (annots != null && annots.Size != 0)
             {
                 foreach (var a in annots)
                 {
                     var newannot = new PdfAnnotation(writer, new Rectangle(0, 0));
                     var annotObj = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a);
                     newannot.PutAll(annotObj);
                     var rect = newannot.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                     rect[0] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[0]).DoubleValue * scale + left); // Left
                     rect[1] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[1]).DoubleValue * scale); // top
                     rect[2] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[2]).DoubleValue * scale + left); // right
                     rect[3] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[3]).DoubleValue * scale); // bottom
                     writer.AddAnnotation(newannot);
                 }
             }

             document.NewPage();
         }

     }

    foreach (var apprPdf in pdfs)
    {
        document.NewPage();

        inlcudePdfInDocument(apprPdf.Pdf, null);
    }

    document.Close();
    readers.ForEach(x => x.Close());
}

output.Position = 0;
return output;
```

PdfReader has a constructor that takes an array of bytes so you can adapt it for MemoryStream.

Comment: This appears to only work for simple annotations which don't reference additional indirect objects.