# How can I copy annotations/highlighting from one PDF to an updated version of that PDF?

Tags: pdf

I've recently moved to almost exclusively electronic books. I prefer to mark up documents with highlighting or annotations as I read them.

However, when I get an updated version of a PDF - O'Reilly, for example, will give access to corrected versions of the books you've purchased - I'm then stuck with a marked up older copy and a newer copy, without my notes.

My preferred language being C# I realize that [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) is probably what I'd need to use if I wanted to programmatically do this (see for example [Copy pdf annotations via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372606/copy-pdf-annotations-via-c)), but is there an easier way to handle this?

I can't believe I'm the only one with this issue, so is there perhaps already a solution that will handle this for me?

Comment: I am also in need of this solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for iTextSharp to approach your problem:

```
var output = new MemoryStream();

using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70f, 70f, 20f, 20f))
{
    var readers = new List<PdfReader>();
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

    writer.CloseStream = false;

    document.Open();

    const Int32 requiredWidth = 500;
    const Int32 zeroBottom = 647;
    const Int32 left = 50;

    Action<String, Action> inlcudePdfInDocument = (filename, e) =>
    {
         var reader = new PdfReader(filename);
         readers.Add(reader);

         var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
         for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
         { 
             e?.Invoke();
             var imp = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, (i + 1));

             var scale = requiredWidth / imp.Width;
             var height = imp.Height * scale;

             writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp, scale, 0, 0, scale, left, zeroBottom - height);

             var annots = reader.GetPageN(i + 1).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
             if (annots != null && annots.Size != 0)
             {
                 foreach (var a in annots)
                 {
                     var newannot = new PdfAnnotation(writer, new Rectangle(0, 0));
                     var annotObj = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.GetPdfObject(a);
                     newannot.PutAll(annotObj);
                     var rect = newannot.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                     rect[0] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[0]).DoubleValue * scale + left); // Left
                     rect[1] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[1]).DoubleValue * scale); // top
                     rect[2] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[2]).DoubleValue * scale + left); // right
                     rect[3] = new PdfNumber(((PdfNumber)rect[3]).DoubleValue * scale); // bottom
                     writer.AddAnnotation(newannot);
                 }
             }

             document.NewPage();
         }

     }

    foreach (var apprPdf in pdfs)
    {
        document.NewPage();

        inlcudePdfInDocument(apprPdf.Pdf, null);
    }

    document.Close();
    readers.ForEach(x => x.Close());
}

output.Position = 0;
return output;
```

This example copies a list of pdf files with annotations into a new pdf file.

Obtain data from two PdfReaders simultaneously - one for copying new pdf and another for copying annotations from old pdf.

Comment: This appears to only work for simple annotations which don't reference additional indirect objects.